# Should questions involving computer versions of card/board games be allowed?

Tags: discussion, computer-questions

[Engines that play Mangala?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/20512/engines-that-play-mangala)

In this question I asked for a Mancala/Mangala game engine. Since this is a computer version of a board game, it was closed. However, [Where can I practice MTG draft online and actually play against my opponents for free?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7267/where-can-i-practice-mtg-draft-online-and-actually-play-against-my-opponents-for), is exactly that. The site must take a decision on this. Please let us decide if we should allow all or none.

Comment: Honestly, this meta question is kind of unnecessary. There are already 3 reopen votes on your question, and the close reason given clearly allows computer versions of board and card games. Your question was closed incorrectly, and that's it. We already have a clear decision on what the rule should be.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I am sorry, but I cannot see reopen votes. Thought I had only one.

Comment: Are we going to have a distinction between 'computer version of a board game' (aka, something you actually play the game on) vs a 'game engine' (something that you program and it plays/simulates something for you)?